# What is the best way to find Array equality in Python ? (Time efficient)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

My goal is to make an image searching (matching) software, matching cause both of them will be identical, so what is the best time-efficient function to use?

Currently, I am using numpy.array_equal() function, if there is more time efficient function let me know. It would be a great help, cause there are more than 800 images.

Does the use of more smaller images, makes the code run faster?

Comment: You can precalculate hashes of the arrays. If two hashes differ, the arrays differ, too. If the hashes match, then call array_equal().

Comment: If, as seems likely, in most cases the two images differ early, you can save a lot of time by comparing `memoryview`s. They are slightly slower than `array_equal` if the arrays are identical, though.

Comment: How can I calculate the hashes of the array?

Comment: [Wikipedia article about hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). For Python implementations, see for instance [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib). Notice though that the hash precomputation will need to read the whole data. (It still helps: if you have N images, comparing each pair of them is O(N**2) operations, so O(N) hash precomputations might be cheaper.)